# JSON Menu Link Without Invoking Init Hooks?

Tags: hooks, ajax, routes

Our Drupal site utilizes a number of menu hooks to return JSON from an API we manage in a separate Web API. We also have a number of intensive tasks that happen on each page load via the `hooks_init` in several custom modules.

The issue we're facing is that the tasks in `hook_init` are only required for actual pages, and should not be executed when all we want is JSON output. Is there a way to ONLY execute the `hook_menu` endpoint, and no other Drupal code?

We have several pages that make 3-4 requests to Drupal JSON menu links, which means that we also run our unnecessary `hook_init` tasks 3-4 times as well -- plus once for the actual page request.

There must be a way to circumvent the usual Drupal pipeline to perform these actions?

Here is an example of one of our JSON menu hooks:

```
function membership_details()
{

    // Get membership details from API, and return as JSON
    $details =  sendCurlResponse(/* ENDPOINT */);
    drupal_json_output($details);
    drupal_exit();
}
```

Comment: According to the comments in `_drupal_bootstrap_full()` that's going to be difficult (if not impossible) inside a normal request. This comes just before `hook_init` is invoked (the only place it's invoked in the core codebase): _Let all modules take action before the menu system handles the request._  Sounds like `hook_init` happening before routing is intentional

Comment: If that's the case, then is there a better way we could structure our JSON endpoints to avoid this issue altogether? Is there any known method of implementing JSON endpoints without using `menu_hooks`?

Comment: I think you're on your own there sadly. I can't think of another mechanism Drupal offers that could help. Perhaps refactoring the code in `hook_init` not to respond on xmlhttprequests is an option? Unsavoury, I know. Or you could implement the routing in custom code and bootstrap Drupal to a lesser level for your JSON endpoints. Not sure of your exact use case there. No nice options spring to mind though I'm afraid

Comment: Sounds like the best approach is not to use Drupal `menu_hook`s for simple JSON output... lol

Answer (score 0):

`hook_init()` is invoked before the menu system deals with the request, and in the confines of a normal Drupal bootstrap, no, it's not possible to circumvent that workflow.

It's by design though, if you look at [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7):

> Perform setup tasks for non-cached page requests.
>
> This hook is run at the beginning of the page request. **It is typically used to set up global parameters that are needed later in the request**. When this hook is called, the theme and all modules are already loaded in memory.

Emphasis mine.

So for its intended use, `hook_init` should only set up variables *that are required for the current request*. Whether that be a request for HTML, JSON, or whatever else.

You have two pretty reasonable options as far as I can tell:

1. Augment the code you have in `hook_init` implementations to check whether it should be executed based on parameters from the request (accepted content type, file extension, whatever makes the most sense for you use case).
2. Move the logic in `hook_init` to another hook, one that's invoked later in the process (I can't really say which hook that would be without knowing what the code does)